# read from stdin python

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments, stdin

I am trying to take a filename input from the first command line argument and if there is none then to read from `stdin` but for some reason my `if` statement does not seem to be working.  I have pasted it below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys


filename=sys.argv[1]

if filename==None:
   filename=sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should check the length of `sys.argv` before trying to index it:

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  filename=sys.argv[1]
else:
  filename=sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

The first element in `sys.argv` is always the filename of the python script, hence the `> 1`.

**[EDIT]**

To expand on fixxxer's answer regarding `is` vs `==`:

`is` returns `True` if the variables compared point to the same object. This holds true for `None`, as `None` is a singleton. `==` on the other hand, returns `True` if the variables compared are equal, i.e. they can point to two distinct (but equal) objects and `==` will yield `True`.

Comment: By replacing `sys.stdin.readlines()` with `sys.stdin.readline()`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, I hit enter after entering my filename and the /n get captured by python.  Is there a way to make sure that that doesn't happen?

Comment: By calling `strip()` on the user input. Updated once again.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Like EventLisle says, check for the size of sys.argv before proceeding.
2. The right way to check if a variable is None is :

   variable is None:

You code could be structured like so:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv[1]):
    filename=sys.argv[1]
    # do your thing
else:
    print "list is empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering as per your code the flow would never reached the if block and it would have throw an IndexError exception in line `filename=sys.argv[1]` , so may be you can try the below code

```
import sys

try:
   filename=sys.argv[1]
except IndexError: 
   filename=sys.stdin.readlines()
```